# Trigonometry: How to determine the Period

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

[image: trigonometry sinusoidal wave]

I'm still kinda confused with solving the period on the diagram above.

Amplitude= $3$
Max = $3$
Min = $-3$
Period = ?

$y=a\cos(bx+c)$

Value of $a$ = $3$

Value of $b$ = ?

Value of $c$ = ?

Comment: A period is the distance between to nearest max. The period is $\pi$ since $\frac{3\pi}{8} -\frac{-\pi}{8} $ gives you half period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizontal distance between consecutive maxima is the period.  The horizontal distance between adjacent maxima and minima is half the period.  In this case, half the period is

$$\frac{3\pi}{8} - \left(-\frac{\pi}{8}\right) = \frac{4\pi}{8} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Hence, a full period is $\pi$.

Since $f(x) = \cos x$ has period $2\pi$, you can determine the frequency of the graph by setting $b\pi = 2\pi$, which yields $b = 2$.  Hence,

$$y = 3\cos(2x + c)$$

To determine $c$, observe that $y = 3$ when $x = -\pi/8$. Hence,

\begin{align*}
3 & = 3\cos\left[2\left(-\frac{\pi}{8}\right) + c\right]\\\
1 & = \cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{4} + c\right)\\
\arccos(1) & = -\frac{\pi}{4} + c\\
0 & = -\frac{\pi}{4} + c\\
\frac{\pi}{4} & = c
\end{align*}

Hence,

$$y = 3\cos\left(2x + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

is a solution.

As a check, evaluate the equation when $x = -\pi/8$ and $x = 3\pi/8$.  If $x = -\pi/8$, then

\begin{align*}
y & = 3\cos\left(2x + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\  
  & = 3\cos\left[2\left(-\frac{\pi}{8}\right) + \frac{\pi}{4}\right]\\
  & = 3\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\
  & = 3\cos(0)\\ 
  & = 3
\end{align*}

If $x = 3\pi/8$, then

\begin{align*}
y & = 3\cos\left(2x + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\  
  & = 3\cos\left[2\left(\frac{3\pi}{8}\right) + \frac{\pi}{4}\right]\\
  & = 3\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\
  & = 3\cos(\pi)\\ 
  & = -3
\end{align*}

These values agree with those shown in the graph.

The solution is not unique.  Since the function has period $\pi$, we could replace

$$c = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

with

$$c = \frac{\pi}{4} + n\pi$$

for any integer $n$ without changing the graph.

Answer (score 4):

$\cfrac{3\pi}{8}-\left(-\cfrac{\pi}{8}\right)$ is half of the period. Hence, the period is $\pi$ i.e. $b=2$ and therefore, $c=\cfrac{\pi}{4}(+n\pi)$.